# Will there be third party compositing with Gnome 3, or will it be limited?

Tags: gnome, compiz, composite

Will we still be able to use Compiz?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a way yes: You will be able to switch away from all the fancy new stuff and just use the gnome-panels like you did with Gnome 2. In this mode it should not be too difficult to replace the WM.

However, in standard, fancy mode you will only be able to use Mutter aka Metacity 3.

Gnome 3 is just too different, it uses lots and lots of composite effects to provide the overlay, animations and a new concept of workspace.

Comment: It's sad to learn that Gnome developers are thinking of dropping Fallback mode at the release of Gnome 3.7 or 3.8. https://live.gnome.org/ThreePointSeven/Features/DropOrFixFallbackMode I love my Classic (Fallback) desktop with Compiz. That will be too bad if they drop the Classic mode. Gnome Shell is also slow as s*** compared to Compiz.